# Hermite polynomial definition

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, special-functions

Can i ask what is the definition for a hermite polynomial. I know that the generating function is $$e^{2xt-t^2}$$ but i dont know whats the explicit definition for $H_{n}$. Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Definition

Comment: Isnt that a definition using nth deriv of a function? I meant, $H_{n}=\sum_..$ something? Not that form.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Explicit_expression